# Functions in Loops for a text based game

Tags: python

I am currently coding a text based game for a class I'm taking.  I want to have a function with nested functions so I don't have to re-write player options in every single room.  Here is what I currently have:

#The loop:

```
while p_choice != 'quit': #begins room loop

#The Forest Clearing

    while room == 'Forest Clearing':

        avail_choices = ['north'] + avail_all
        room_inv = [] #items in this room
        room_desc = ("\nYou are in The Forest Clearing. To the north you see a large cave\n"
                 "with stone stairs leading down. There doesn\'t seem to be anything\n"
                 "you can do here...\n")

        if p_choice == 'north':
            print("\nYou step through the cave entrance and walk cautiously down the 
                stairs.\n"
                "You find yourself in some sort of cavern, filled with an inky darkness. It is 
                 far too\n"
                "dark to see much, but nearby, you see a pile of rubbish with a flashlight 
                 sitting on top.")
            room = rooms[room][p_choice]
        elif p_choice not in avail_choices:
            print('You can\'t do that here!')
            room = [room]
        else:
            all_rooms()
```

#Function I'm trying to call

```
 def all_rooms():
     def look():
         if p_choice == 'look':
             print(room_desc)
             room = [room]
```

I want it to return to the loop after printing the room description. It prints the room description like I want, but then it crashes and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jwpru\Desktop\IT140-P1\TextBasedGame.py", line 136, in <module>
    all_rooms()
  File "C:\Users\jwpru\Desktop\IT140-P1\TextBasedGame.py", line 95, in all_rooms
    look()
  File "C:\Users\jwpru\Desktop\IT140-P1\TextBasedGame.py", line 72, in look
    room = [room]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'room' referenced before assignment
You are in The Forest Clearing. To the north you see a large cave
with stone stairs leading down. There doesn't seem to be anything
you can do here...
```

I've also tried:

```
 def all_rooms():
     def look():
         if p_choice == 'look':
             print(room_desc)
             global room
```

and...

```
 def all_rooms():
     def look():
          global room
          if p_choice == 'look':
               print(room_desc)
               room = [room]
```

Not sure what to do here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The last version should have worked. But are you really sure you want to set `room` to a list? It looks like the rest of the code expects it to be a string.

Comment: No, I definitely don't want it to be a list... I actually realized that part was wrong and fixed it like this: 

    room = rooms[room][p_choice]

which works okay.  I found a work around for the issue I was having with the functions by doing this: 

     def all_rooms():
     def look():
          if p_choice == 'look':
               global p_choice
               print(room_desc)
               p_choice = print("What would you like to do?: ") 

Which pushes it back to the global player choice field. That got it looping properly, though it wasn't really what I had in mind...

Comment: In any case, using `global room` should work.